# How do you align the navbarPage() Title to be in the middle of the navbar?

Tags: r, shiny, tags, navbar

This is the top left hand corner of my navbar (created using `navbarPage()`).

[image]

How do you get the white text to align into the middle of the navbar, i.e. somewhere near the cats eyes (which is my logo.png)? This 'white text' is actually my `navbarPage()` title. Also, how do you remove the square that this title points at. The square is generated as a result of a blank title argument from a later `tabPanel()` function. I don't want to show the title. Im essentially asking how you remove the tabpanel() navigation 'button' from the top of your navbar, without actually removing the tabPanel() and tabsetPanel() from within the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Aligning the text in the middle:

**html**

```html
<div class='test'>
  <p>test title</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Could you paste some code here for the rest?

Comment: Hero! I used this "<div class='navbar-header'>
                            <span class='navbar-brand'>App Title</span>
                            </div>"  to pin it to the title

Comment: For the second part: navbarPage(title = "App Title", theme = shinytheme("cosmo"), navbarPage(title = "abc", tabPanel(title = 'abc', sidebarLayout(**rest of UI**... i added abc to represent the title that would be generated in the square box indicated in the pic above. Thanks so much for your .css, it was driving me insane :)